# Tikz - LaTex - Creating the vertices of a triangle using arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a .sty file for my project and I'm trying to write a newcommand in there to take 3 arguments that are the 3 side lengths of a triangle and then draw the triangle. I'm not quite sure how to apply a math formula to set a co-ordinate. Here is what I have so far:

```
\newcommand{\drawtriangle}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (#2,0);
\coordinate (C) at  ((${#2^2+#3^2-#1^2}/{2*#2}$),(${#3^2-{{#2^2+#3^2-#1^2}/{2*#2}}^2}^{0.5}$));
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: if you know side lengths a, b, c you can use law of cosine to figure out θ, the angle between a and b. Next, put one vertices at (0, 0), one at (a, 0), and one at (θ:b).

Comment: It seems you had figured out the formulas. So the missing ingredient is `\pgfmathsetmacro`, which lets you perform mathematical computations

Answer (score 1):

I believe this solves the problem

```latex
\newcommand{\drawtriangle}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (#1,0);
\coordinate (C) at  ({(#1^2+#2^2-#3^2)/(2*#1)},{sqrt(#2^2-((#1^2+#2^2-#3^2)/(2*#1))^2)});
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;  
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

It looks like you're using `{}` when you should be using `()`.

Either way, the formulas are obtained by the intersections of circles.

[image]

It would have to add conditions for the existence of the triangle. But I think that's enough to help you.

Comment: The equation at the upper vertex is for c^2, not b^2.